# Boolean value in database doesnot update Larave

Tags: laravel

I tried to change the boolean value if it is true make it false and vice versa

```
public function switch($pid){


 $post=Post::find($pid);

if($post->status){

 $post->status=0;

}

if(!$post->status){

 $post->status=1;   

}

$post->save();

}
```

Comment: More info please

Comment: i want to change the boolean value but it work when the value is 0 I can able to change to 1 But when it is set to 1 then I cant set back to 0 WHy??

Comment: What is the value of status at the moment? `dd($post->status);`

Comment: now the value is 1...... when it is 0 I can able to change But when it is 1 i cant

Comment: `$post->status = ! $post->status;`
`$post->save();`
This should work.

Comment: Did it work?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$post->status = ! $post->status;
$post->save();
```